# laravel5 composer require pacage show zlib_decode(): data error everytime

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, composer-php

laravel5 composer require pacage show zlib_decode(): data error everytime

```html
D:\wamp\www\laravel-v5.1.1>composer require "michelf/php-markdown:1.4.*"
./composer.json has been updated
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Failed to decode response: zlib_decode(): data error
Retrying with degraded mode, check https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/troubleshooting.md#degraded-mode for more info
```

Is anyone know what happened ?

Answer (score 0):

try running this command

```
composer config --global repositories.packagist.allow_ssl_downgrade false
```

then run

```
composer install
```

Answer (score 0):

I used the `composer require "michelf/php-markdown:1.4.*"` for this package and it worked.

Try `composer clear-cache` maybe?